# Job wide custom cleanup after all the map tasks are completed

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

While running a map-reduce job, that has only mapper, I have a counter that counts the number of failed documents .And after all the mappers are done, I want the job to fail if the total number of failed documents are above a fixed fraction. ( I need it in the end because I don't know the total number of documents initially). How can I achieve this without implementing a reduce just for this ?

I know that there are task level cleanup method. But is there any job level cleanup method, that can be used to perform this after all the tasks are done ?

Comment: Do you want to stop the job if the counter exceeds threshold in mapper itself?

Comment: I want to throw an exception, when all mappers are done and then check and fail if the value of the counter is above a threshold. I get the fraction of the failed documents when all the mappers finish.

Comment: Are you trying to fail the job in the middle.The job will be over when all mappers are done(Since no reducers).So you dont have to kill the job.You can get Counters once the entire job is done

Answer (score 0):

This can be done very easily. Thats the beauty of latest mapreduce API.

The execution of a mapper can be controlled with the help of overriding run method in Mapper class, and same way for the reducer. I do not know the final outcome that you are expecting. But, i have prepared a small example for you. I have

in my mapper class, i have overriden run method and giving you a sample, it iterrupts the execution if the key value is greater than 200 in my code.

```
public class ReversingMapper extends Mapper<LongWritable, Text, ReverseIntWritable, Text> 
{
    public final LongWritable border = new LongWritable(100);
    @Override
      public void run(Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        setup(context);

          while (context.nextKeyValue()) {

             /*   extra code to standard run method started here                 */

            //if(context.getCounter(<ENUM>) > 200 ){}  -- you can place your counter check here.
            if(context.getCurrentKey().get() > 200 )
            {
                throw new InterruptedException();
            }else
            {
            /*   extra code to standard run method ended here                 */
                map(context.getCurrentKey(), context.getCurrentValue(), context);
            }
          }

      }
```

and you need to handle in properly in the Driver as well.

```
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.exit(0);
        }
```

You can have logger and even log a proper message that is required here..

I hope this solves your problem. Let me know if you need any more help.